# Android Studio git clone failure

Tags: git, android-studio

I encountered some problems while using Andoird Studio. I updated to Windows 10 Pro and now I'm not able to update or pull new versions via Android Studio. So I reinstalled Android Studio and git. Went into the settings and set the correct path to git.

[image: Git install proof]

After reinstalling everthing I wanted to check out my project again but it just won't do it. First when I press "Test" the message "Repository test has failed" appears. Second when I press "Clone" the message "Clone failed. unable to read askpass response  from..." pops up.

[image: askpass error]

Clone respository via git command line works fine and I also can clone via SourceTree. So my assumption is that the problem lies on Android Studio. Google search doesn't gave me the right answers and I dont know what else I could do or try out. Does someone has any tips how I could solve this problem?